# how to give a user a model field to choose from during signup?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

how to make a user registration form including a model field in it as a required field?

like i want `college` field to show up on registration page as a drop-down menu

my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    college = models.ForeignKey(College, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()


class College(models.Model):
    col = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.col
```

my forms.py

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    col = College.objects.all()
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    college = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=col))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'college', 'password1', 'password2',)
```

and the views.py includes this:

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        user.refresh_from_db()
        user.save()
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = UserForm()
return render(request, 'registration_form.html', {'form': form})
```

**UPDATE**

got to know about ModelChoiceField and made these changes in forms.py:

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
college = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=College.objects.all(), empty_label=None)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'college', 'password1', 'password2')
```

but the college chosen is not being saved in the profile

also the admin section is giving an `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/` error

Comment: Could you add the college to the Profile record in the view? (Not sure of the timing of the signal that creates the Profile)

Comment: @Dashdrum i dont see how that would help as the forms.py is supposed to handle the fields, not the views.py

Comment: The form only knows about fields in the User model.  You'll have to save the college separately.  I would do it in the form_valid part of your view.